# radio button css missing on safari

Tags: html, css, vue.js, safari, bootstrap-vue

I have a vue app that runs almost fine on chrome browser but some issues crop up on safari. The main issue is with the components which have radio buttons. When I click on any of the radio options it doesn't show the selected color(blue)(but the option is being selected in my responses JSON). However, if you click again on the same option it appears. Why does this happen on Safari, can anyone guide me? It works fine on Chrome.

the UI is here: https://sensein.github.io/covid19/#/activities/0

and the code is here: https://github.com/sanuann/schema-ui/blob/master/src/components/Inputs/WebRadio/Radio.vue

The entire build is carried out by Github actions and deployed via gh-pages.

Comment: The radio buttons go blue on the first click using Safari IOS14.

Comment: @AHaworth what about on macOS?

Comment: Haven’t got a macOS machine I’m afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by removing the watch on "init" here: https://github.com/sanuann/schema-ui/blob/master/src/components/Inputs/WebRadio/Radio.vue#L105

I am not sure why it worked in other browsers and why the problem occured on Safari only. anyways was able to fix it.